# Passenger Error

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

Problem: 
My web page produce 502 Bad Gateway error. Upon reviewing the logs in /var/log/nginx/error.log I found this error:

[error] 1245#0: *6358 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.KMnpQom/agents.s/server failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x , server: x.x.x.x , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.KMnpQom/agents.s/server:", host: "x.x.com"

I restated nginx and everything is fine again. But Please I want to know what is cause of this problem and what i need to do prevent it from happening again.

I need your assistance;

thank you

Comment: Is there a error message in the application's log file (`#{Rails.root}/log/production.log`)?

Comment: railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'

Comment: No Error found in production.log file But these are some of the outputs: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:414:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'

Comment: It seems like your Ruby version doesn't know the `public_send` method. `public_send` was introduced in Ruby 1.9. Is it possible that your server runs the application with an older version of Ruby?

Comment: This is my versions of programs running:                                                   Nginx version : 1.80
phusion passenger version : 5.0.10
Ruby version : 2.0.0p643

Comment: Can you please copy'n'paste the error message with the whole stack trace into your question?

Comment: I have resolved it; but this is message :                                               [error] 1245#0: *6345 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.KMnpQom/agents.s/server failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 147.175.88.88, server: 138.197.222.103, request: "GET /issues/18250 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.KMnpQom/agents.s/server:", host: "redmine.aaa.com.

Comment: RESOLVED !!!!                                                                                                    This is often caused by your server automatically cleaning  the /tmp directory and removes the passenger instance directory there. So I  move the dir elsewhere using the passenger_instance_registry_dir config option (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_instance_registry_dir)